# Numerical rank deficiency in P-spline based varying coefficient model

Tags: regression, splines, time-varying-covariate

I am studying the following varying coefficient model from [1]:

$$
d_x(x,y) =  s_x(y)x + c_x(y) + o_x(x)
$$
$$
d_y(x,y) = s_y(y)x + c_y(y) + o_y(x) 
$$

where $x$ and $y$ are covariates, $d_x$ and $d_y$ are data coming from measurements and $s_{x,y}(y)$,$c_{x,y}(y)$,$o_{x,y}(x)$, are smooth functions modeled by P-splines [2]. The main goal is to recover the coefficients of these P-splines in order to use the model to make predictions. These model equations can be used to assemble the cost function
$$
c_x(\mathbf{p}) = ||\mathbf{d}-A \mathbf{p}||^2+\lambda_s ||D_s \mathbf{p_s}||^2
+\lambda_c ||D_c \mathbf{p_c}||^2+\lambda_o ||D_o \mathbf{p_o}||^2
$$
where $\mathbf{p}=\left[\mathbf{p_s}\, \mathbf{p_c}\, \mathbf{p_o} \right]$ is the vector collecting all the spline coefficients to be estimated, $A$ is a matrix whose blocks have elements computed by evaluating the B-spline bases in the data points abscissas $\{ x_i \}$ and ordinates $\{ y_i \}$, $\mathbf{d}$ is the vector of measurements, $D_s$, $D_c$ and $D_o$ are the second order divided difference operators used to enforce smoothness of $\mathbf{p}$ and the $\lambda$'s are tuning parameters. For more details please see [2]. Given the linearity of the cost gradient, we can estimate $\mathbf{p}$ by solving the linear least squares problem:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{p}} = (A^TA + P)^{-1} A^T \mathbf{d}
$$
$$
P = \text{diag}(\lambda_s D_s^T D_s,\lambda_c D_c^T D_c,\lambda_o D_o^T D_o)
$$

When I solve this linear system using synthetic data for $\mathbf{d}$ I see that the matrix to be inverted as well as the $A$ matrix are numerically rank deficient. To cope with this I use a minimum norm least square solver. The authors of [2] suggest in some of their papers to redefine the $P$ matrix as $P = \text{diag}(\lambda_s D_s^T D_s,\lambda_c D_c^T D_c,\lambda_o D_o^T D_o) + \lambda I$ with
$\lambda=10^{-6}$ to reach the same goal.

Now my question is: is the ill-conditioning of this linear system something generally expected in these models? Are there more principled ways to address it?

[1] Saquib, Suhail S.et al. "Spline warp model for registering pushbroom multispectral imagery." Long-Range Imaging II. Vol. 10204. SPIE, 2017.

[2] Eilers, Paul HC, and Brian D. Marx. Practical smoothing: The joys of P-splines. Cambridge University Press, 2021.

Comment: The penalties are what should make the system full rank. From your question, I don't see what $P$ is supposed to be besides just $P = \lambda I$. If that's the case, then this problem is identifiable when $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear, in the most general case $P = \text{diag}(\lambda_s D_s^T D_s,\lambda_c D_c^T D_c,\lambda_o D_o^T D_o) + \lambda I$ with $\lambda >= 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as $P$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries on the diagonal, then $(A^tA + P)$ should be invertible and the solution should be unique.

Comment: This is correct, however as I point out the problem is not inversion of $(A^{\rm T}A+P)$ but its very high condition number. I see condition numbers of the order of $10^{20}$. Now I suspect that this is caused by an identifiability problem.

Comment: @ArrigoBenedetti is it possible that the issue is that there are penalties which are too small then? The larger the penalties, the smaller the conditioning number.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too, however increasing the $\lambda$s did not help. I believe that the problem is identifiability of the model. You can add $\delta$ to $c_x(y)$ and subtract it from $o_x(x)$, for example, and the model will still fit the data with a low error. In my specific problem I see actually two unidentified parameters since there are two singular values close to machine precision. I was able to eliminate one using the reparameterization method presented in Wood's book on GAMs, but there is still a parameter that I cannot identify.

Comment: Have you removed intercepts from 2 out of 3 of the splines? I believe if you have intercepts in all the spline expansions, you will get non-identifiability.

Comment: P-splines do not have an explicit intercept term, however they can model a generic function with an offset. Usually they are constrained with a method like that presented in Sec. 5.4.1 of Wood, Generalized additive models: an introduction with R. Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2006.

Comment: I posted a new question specific to identifiability here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606178/identifiability-of-simple-varying-coefficient-model